Sticky bit doesn't allow to delete or rename a file within a directory
As shown below, on my Ubuntu system, carlo directory has the sticky bit permission set. It contains the file file1 owned by user lab.
lab@ubuntu:~$ ll | grep carlo
drwxrwxr-t  2 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Oct 31 08:09 carlo/

lab@ubuntu:~$ ll /home/ubuntu/carlo/file1 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lab ubuntu 0 Oct 31 08:09 /home/ubuntu/carlo/file1
lab@ubuntu:~$

As you can see user lab owns file1, yet he can't rename or delete the file.
lab@ubuntu:~$ mv /home/ubuntu/carlo/file1 /home/ubuntu/carlo/file2
mv: cannot move '/home/ubuntu/carlo/file1' to '/home/ubuntu/carlo/file2': Permission denied

lab@ubuntu:~$ rm /home/ubuntu/carlo/file1
rm: cannot remove '/home/ubuntu/carlo/file1': Permission denied
lab@ubuntu:~$

Is this an expected behavior?

I’m guessing lab isn’t in the ubuntu group; this means that they don’t have write permission in carlo, so they can’t create or rename files in that directory. The sticky bit isn’t relevant here.
So yes, this is expected. To get the behaviour you’re after, add write permissions for others:
chmod o+w carlo

See Understanding UNIX permissions and file types for details.

Ah ok. I added write permission for others to carlo directory (yes, user lab isn't member of ubuntu group).
lab@ubuntu:~$ ll | grep carlo drwxrwxrwt  2 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Oct 31 16:07 carlo/. Now it works !

However, even ubuntu user can delete file1. Why if sticky bit is set on carlo directory?

The directory’s owner can always delete files in the directory.

As directory's owner do you mean the directory's user owner?

Yes, the owner user (not group).

Ok, it works as expected !
